# Retrieve data to text view from fire base without parent key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is firebase database details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pBDH.png)

Here I want to search details using child without use parent key. According to this database, I want to get price and category using Name without using parent key ("kjhsfkgkrlhg"), ("get price, category where Name="super Creamcracker")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference itemsRef = rootRef.child("Items");
Query query = itemsRef.orderByChild("Name").equalsTo("super Creamcracker");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String category = ds.child("Category").getValue(String.class);
            long price = ds.child("Price").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d("TAG", category + " / " + price);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

So the `ds` contains a list of results. Even if there is only a single result, the `ds` will contain a list of one result. So the output will be:

```
200g / 200
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you make database reference first

```
DatabaseReference itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items");
```

then,

```
String itemName = "super Creamcracker"; 

Query query = itemRef.orderByChild("Name").startAt(itemName).endAt(itemName+ "\uf8ff");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //if you dont have class for item
                String price = data.child("Price").getValue().toString();
                String category = data.child("Category").getValue().toString();


                //if you have class, lets say Item.java
                Item item = data.getValue(Item.class);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i try to assign price and category value to text view.in the for loop i type  nam.setText(category)  and  pric.setText(price) nam and pric are id of textview,but its not work

Comment: hmm.. try to toast/log it first inside for loop, test if the data is obtained successfuly or not

Comment: Thanx andikaa_app..its work after using database refer for Query